# How to create a master dictionary from a from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {1: 2,
2:3,
3: 4,
5:6,
6:7}
```

I want this output:

```
d= { 1: 4 , 2 :4 , 3:4 , 5:7 , 6:7}
```

basically 2 is parent of 1, 3 is parent of 2, 4 is parent of 3. I want to say that 1,2 and 3 is related to 4

Comment: What's the use case? Depending on how that dictionary is created could influence the answer here. It might help to add some supporting code and context as to what you are doing

Comment: Are you just trying to set all the values to the same number?

Comment: @wjandrea Even simpler: `dict.fromkeys(d, d[3])`.

Comment: please check the edit once

Comment: Does it alternate every 3? What is the logic?

Comment: To make it more clear, assume it's a list of dictionary

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Making it a list of dicts doesn't make it any clearer. It only makes it harder to access the key-value pairs. Reverted the question to be based on a dict for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

For each key-value pair in the dict, you can use a `while` loop to keep checking if the current value is a valid key in the dict, and make the value of that key the new value, until the value is not a key, at which point you have found the leaf and you can assign that value to the current key:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    while v in d:
        v = d[v]
    d[k] = v
```

so that given:

```
d = {1: 2,
     2: 3,
     3: 4,
     5: 6,
     6: 7}
```

`d` becomes:

```
{1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 5: 7, 6: 7}
```

Comment: Update your question with a sample of the large dictionary that replicates the issue then.